# autonum, subcaption and equations in floats

Tags: subcaption, autonum

When compiling the document below (MiKTeX lualatex or pdflatex) latex seems to be stuck in an infinite loop. Removing either subcaption or autonum resolves the problem, but of course I'd like to use them both.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{subcaption}
\usepackage{autonum}
\begin{document}

\begin{figure}
\begin{equation}
1 = 1
\end{equation}
\end{figure}

\begin{figure}
\caption{X}\label{fig}
\end{figure}

\end{document}
```

I can interrupt latex and get this message:

```
[...]
ABD: EveryShipout initializing macros
! Interruption.
\new@ifnextchar ...rved@d = #1\def \reserved@a {#2
                                                  }\def \reserved@b {#3}\fut...
l.17 \caption{X}\label{fig}

? x
 3143 words of node memory still in use:
    nodes
   avail lists: 1:3,2:19,4:5,6:10,7:2,8:2,9:1,10:2
No pages of output.
Transcript written on minimal.log.
```

It looks like one of the packages has a problem with equations in floats. I do this to let an long equation span the whole page in a two-column layout. I assume autonum looks back to see whether the `\label` references an equation, but I don't know why this conflicts with subcaption.

Thanks for your help.

Comment: Possibly related to `autonum` bug mentioned at http://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/158579/captionautonuma-certain-structure-freeze??

Comment: @Steven: seems to be the same but with `caption` instead of `subcaption`. Duplicate then?

Comment: It may be the same bug, though this seems like a different manifestation.  I would leave the question, unless others vote to close it.

Comment: In your MnWE you got one figure without a caption and one with a caption as the only contents, both are unlikely structures. If equation and caption are both put in the same  figure the apparent bug doesn’t trigger.

Comment: @Crissov Yes, but as soon as you have *two* figures, with *two* equations and *two* captions - an extremely likely structure - you have trouble.

Comment: @Crissov This is an extract of a much larger document to get a minimal example. In the large document there is of course some content in the second figure. It triggers as soon as there is an equation (or align) in a float followed anywhere in the document by a `\label` of a table or figure. Hardly an unusual structure although not everyone puts equations into floats.

Comment: @cfr, OP: Okay, seems my tests weren’t advanced enough to catch that and the problem description didn’t say much beyond “When compiling the document below”.