# Bad interaction between autonomy and caption packages?

Tags: floats, cross-referencing, captions, autonum

I've found this strange error when using the `autonum` and `caption` package together, and placing an equation inside a float.

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage{caption}
\usepackage{autonum}

\begin{document}

\begin{figure}
  \begin{equation}
    x^2+1=0
  \end{equation}
\end{figure}

\section{LoL}
\label{lol}

\end{document}
```

The error points to the `\label` command, suggesting the control sequence `\caption@x@label` is undefined.

```
! Undefined control sequence.
\caption@@xlabel ...abelname {#2}\caption@x@label
                                                  #1{#2}
l.22 \label{lol}
```

The error disappears if I comment either `\usepackage{caption}` or `\usepackage{autonum}`.

Am I doing something wrong? Is it a bug of either package? Is there a workaround I can use?

Comment: Related post: https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/160579.

Comment: putting an equation in a float is a pretty odd thing to do (although it's not normally an error) latex doesn't really support it, the equations would typically be numbered out of sequence.

Comment: Of course it's odd alone, but in my document is a part of a picture that illustrates the formula, so it makes sense. Anyway, the problem arises specifically with the `autonum` package, apparently.

Comment: @RuixiZhang the problem seems related indeed. Any progress since 2014?